# How to assign the output of a Bash command to a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a problem putting the content of `pwd` command into a shell variable that I'll use later.

Here is my shell code (the loop doesn't stop):

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd= `pwd`
until [ $pwd = "/" ]
    do
        echo $pwd
        ls && cd .. && ls 
        $pwd= `pwd` 
    done
```

Could you spot my mistake, please?

Comment: You could also add an escape hatch to your loops in case something goes wrong. e.g. `i=0` oustide of the loop. then inside, `i=$i + 1`. And then also inside the loop, add something like `if [ $i > 25 ] then; break; endif;` I'm not sure of the loop breaking in syntax in shell scripts, but it should be something like that.

Comment: @ButtleButkus, `[ $i > 25 ]`, is exactly the same as `[ $i ] >25`; that is to say, `25` is treated as a filename. You need to use `-gt` for numeric comparisons, or quote `'>'` for string comparisons. And adding one to `i` is `i=$(( i + 1))`; the syntax you have now tries to run the command `+` with the argument `1` and `i` set in its environment. And the keyword for ending an `if` in shell is `fi`.

Answer (score 398, accepted):

Try:

```
pwd=`pwd`
```

or

```
pwd=$(pwd)
```

> Notice no spaces after the equals sign.

Also as Mr. Weiss points out; you don't assign to `$pwd`, you assign to `pwd`.

Comment: great, thank you so much :)
will definatly remember that no spaces and $ sign

Comment: works great, but what does `$()` mean in `$(pwd)`?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo `$()` in bash just replaces itself with the output of the command executed with the braces; so `$(pwd)` would expand to `/home/ubuntu` for example, making the assignment the equivalent of: `pwd='/home/ubuntu'`

Comment: @JohnWeldon `cd $pwd/newdir` does this work if the `newdir` exists?

Comment: myPwd=$(pwd) then to output the result: $myPwd

Comment: @JohnWeldon It is doing more than just executing a command and assigning the results to a variable. It is creating a whole new subshell. There is a lot going on when using subshells beyond just capturing the results of a command.

Answer (score 44):

In shell you assign to a variable without the dollar-sign:

```
TEST=`pwd`
echo $TEST
```

that's better (and can be nested) but is not as portable as the backtics:

```
TEST=$(pwd)
echo $TEST
```

Always remember: the dollar-sign is only used when reading a variable.

Comment: Remember to use lower case for your variable names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization

Comment: And remember to [quote your variables](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642).

Answer (score 22):

In this specific case, note that bash has a variable called [`PWD`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PWD-229) that contains the current directory: `$PWD` is equivalent to `` `pwd` ``. (So do other shells, this is a [standard feature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_03).) So you can write your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
until [ "$PWD" = "/" ]; do
  echo "$PWD"
  ls && cd .. && ls 
done
```

Note the use of double quotes around the variable references. They are necessary if the variable (here, the current directory) contains whitespace or wildcards (`\[?*`), because the shell splits the result of variable expansions into words and performs globbing on these words. **Always double-quote variable expansions `"$foo"` and command substitutions `"$(foo)"`** (unless you specifically know you have not to).

In the general case, as other answers have mentioned already:

- You can't use whitespace around the equal sign in an assignment: `var=value`, not <strike>`var = value`</strike>
- The `$` means “take the value of this variable”, so you don't use it when assigning: `var=value`, not <strike>`$var=value`</strike>.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `$PWD` is an internal part of bash. This gets confusing when you have a `PWD=\`pwd\`` in your script and then you `pushd` to another directory and expect `$PWD` is holding the dir before `pushd` and it doesn't!

Answer (score 14):

You can also do way more complex commands, just to round out the examples above. So, say I want to get the number of processes running on the system and store it in the *${NUM_PROCS}* variable.

All you have to so is generate the command pipeline and stuff it's output (the process count) into the variable.

It looks something like this:

```
NUM_PROCS=$(ps -e | sed 1d | wc -l)
```

I hope that helps add some handy information to this discussion.

Comment: Using an all-caps variable name is an unfortunate decision -- all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are guaranteed not to have unintended side effects in POSIX-compliant shells. For example, on ksh93, `JOBMAX` changes the number of background tasks that can be running at once; it's not hard to imagine a shell using `NUM_PROCS` for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your script...

```
DIR=$(pwd)
echo $DIR
while [ "$DIR" != "/" ]; do
    cd ..
    DIR=$(pwd)
    echo $DIR
done
```

Note the spaces, use of quotes, and $ signs.

Comment: Remember to use lower case for your variable names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization

Comment: Also, `echo "$DIR"`, with the quotes; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).