# Assigning the output of a command to a variable

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I am new with unix and I am writing a shell script.

When I run this line on the command prompt, it prints the total count of the number of processes which matches:

```
ps -ef | awk '/siebsvc –s siebsrvr/ && !/awk/ { a++ } END { print a }'
```

example, the output of the above line is 2 in the command prompt.

I want to write a shell script in which the output of the above line (2) is assigned to a variable, which will be later be used for comparison in an if statement.

I am looking for something like

```
output= `ps -ef | awk '/siebsvc –s siebsrvr/ && !/awk/ { a++ } END { print a }'`
echo $output
```

But when i run it, it says output could not be found whereas I am expecting 2. Please help.

Comment: Have you taken note of the space between `output=` and `ps...`? Try after getting rid of it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign the output of a Bash command to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2314750/608639)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use a `$` sign like:

```
OUTPUT=$(expression)
```

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
output=$(ps -ef | awk '/siebsvc –s siebsrvr/ && !/awk/ { a++ } END { print a }'); echo $output
```

Wrapping your command in `$( )` tells the shell to run that command, instead of attempting to set the command itself to the variable named "output". (Note that you could also use backticks `command`.)

I can highly recommend http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html to learn more about command substitution.

Also, as 1_CR correctly points out in a comment, the extra space between the equals sign and the assignment is causing it to fail. Here is a simple example on my machine of the behavior you are experiencing:

```
jed@MBP:~$ foo=$(ps -ef |head -1);echo $foo
UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD

jed@MBP:~$ foo= $(ps -ef |head -1);echo $foo
-bash: UID: command not found
UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do it with multiline/multiple command/s then you can do this:

```
output=$( bash <<EOF
#multiline/multiple command/s
EOF
)
```

Or:

```
output=$(
#multiline/multiple command/s
)
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="$( bash <<EOF
echo first
echo second
echo third
EOF
)"
echo "$output"
```

Output:

```
first
second
third
```