# Store the grep result of a maven command in a variable

Tags: shell, maven, gitlab-ci

I want to `grep` the result of a `maven` (`maven-help` plugin) command and store the `grep` result in a shell variable and use it in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

I've tried this and the `maven` command prints the desired result, but `echo $VERSION` prints nothing (i.e. `VERSION` variable is empty):

```
VERSION= mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version
```

I've also tried this and it gets error: `Downloading:: command not found`:

```
VERSION= $(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate "-Dexpression=project.version" | grep -v '\[')
```

So how can i store the `grep` result in a variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assigning the output of a command to a variable in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688552/assigning-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-variable-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space after the `=`, that is:

```
VERSION=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate "-Dexpression=project.version")
```

Comment: You can do it inside the `$(...)`