# assign the multiline output of command to a variable

Tags: bash

I need to assign multiline output of command to a variable.
I read these two threads:

[assigning the output of a command to a variable in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688552/assigning-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-variable-in-a-shell-script)

[Capturing multiple line output into a Bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613572/capturing-multiple-line-output-into-a-bash-variable)

and it works for echo example (multiline commands):

```
#!/bin/bash
output="$( bash <<EOF
echo first
echo second
echo third
EOF
)"
echo "$output"
```

but it seems to not working for one command with multiline output. When I run

```
output="$( bash <<EOF
echo abc
uncrustify -c ~/.uncrustify.cfg --check filename
echo def
EOF
)"
```

I will receive the second line of default `uncrustify -c ~/.uncrustify.cfg --check filename` output:

`FAIL: filename (File size changed from 404 to 417)`

Default output for `uncrustify -c ~/.uncrustify.cfg --check filename` is:

```
Parsing: filename as language OC
FAIL: filename (File size changed from 404 to 417)
```

I want to assign both of these lines to output variable and hide all outputs to console.

Comment: When you say it is `not working` for the 2nd part? What is the output you are getting

Comment: I'm getting `FAIL: filename (File size changed from 404 to 417)` what is unexpected. I should get nothing in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try:

```
output=`echo abc && uncrustify -c ~/.uncrustify.cfg --check filename && echo def`
```

Or better yet, to get the variable to store new lines:

```
output="$(echo abc)\n$(uncrustify -c ~/.uncrustify.cfg --check filename 2>&1)\n$(echo def)"
echo -e "$output"
```

Please note the `-e` flag used with `echo`, as this enables it to translate the `\n` sequence into a newline.

Comment: I created script.sh and added `output="$(echo abc)\n$(uncrustify -c ~/.uncrustify.cfg --check filename)\n$(echo def)"` in it (without echo line). I run script in console by ./script.sh and got `FAIL: filename (File size changed from 404 to 417)` to console what I did not want.

Comment: The same with your first option.

Comment: I realised that `FAIL: filename (File size changed from 404 to 417)` is a text from `stderr`. How to put also it to variable?

Comment: This is because of your script prints to stderr, you should apply the line from my edited answer.