# How to store a multiline output of cat command in different variables?

Tags: bash

I read the following posts regarding saving a multi line output to a variable
[assign the multiline output of command to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500178/assign-the-multiline-output-of-command-to-a-variable)

I am not able to save each line into a different variable , I tried using an array but somehow the length of the array is always zero

```
my_array=()
cat check_status | while read line || [[ -n $line ]] ;
do
    echo $line
    my_array+=( $line)
done
echo ${#my_array[@]}
echo ${my_array[0]} 
echo ${my_array[1]}
```

The length of the array is always 0 and the contents of the array are always blank

my output of cat is

```
alpha
beta
```

I want to save each of the line into a different variable. I am new to shell script so unsure if  using array was the best solution here.

Comment: Just `mapfile` or `readarray` (which is the same command). `but somehow` https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: was able to use mapfile ,Thanks  @KamilCuk