# Using the hostname in a String

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to use the hostname of a linux device into a string for that here's what I'm trying:

app.sh

```
flowname="flow_${hostname}.txt"
echo "$flowname"
```

running the script delivers the following output : `flow_.txt`

any idea what I'm missing here ? 
thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign the output of a Bash command to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2314750/608639), [Assigning the output of a command to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20688552/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in variable named `$hostname`. Try the variable `$HOST` or the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) `$(hostname)` instead.

```
flowname="flow_$HOST.txt"
```

```
flowname="flow_$(hostname).txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `${VARIABLE}` syntax is used to substitute the value of the given variable.

You want to execute the `hostname` command.
By using the above variable substitution you try to output a variable called 'hostname' which does not exist.

You have to use the `$(COMMAND)` syntax. This will execute the given command and print its result.

Answer (score 0):

Try "uname -n", the "uname" command gives interesting information on your host.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script under ubuntu on WSL (windows subsytem for linux) and found the comment of John Kugelman useful.

To make the script functioning in this environment, i first print out the available system environment variables.

```
printenv | less
```

then I chosen to replace ${hostname} with ${NAME}.

Answer (score -1):

You need variables that are populated. Use the command `env` to list environment variables,

```
env
```

So, just populate hostname,

```
hostname=$(uname -n)
echo ${hostname}
flowname="flow_${hostname}.txt"
echo "$flowname"
```