# Bash: how to pass commands to a function

Tags: bash, output, eval, variable-assignment, assign

I have a function that is supposed to evaluate the command passed to it as a string and display the output if the command failed. However, I'm getting some problems:

```
 $(echo "pwd")
```

works well (I see the files and directories). But, when I want to retrieve the output of this command:

```
 var=$(echo "pwd")
 echo ${var}
```

I get the following output:

```
 pwd
```

Why does assigning a variable to the output cause such a significant change? I've looked it up and it seems to be the recommended way of retrieving the output (i.e. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)).

Also, I based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005192/how-to-execute-a-bash-command-stored-as-a-string-with-quotes-and-asterisk) question and tried a different approach:

```
cmd="ls"
$cmd
file1 file2 dir1
a=$cmd
echo ${a}
ls
```

The result is the same like for the previous approach. I have the same issue with the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314750/how-to-assign-the-output-of-a-bash-command-to-a-variable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash).

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the output of a string evaluated as a command?

**Edit:** I tried using `$()`:

```
> var="pwd"
> ${var}
/c/Users/myDir
> $(${var})
bash: /c/Users/myDir: Is a directory
```

**Edit2:** I need to change the current working directory, so, as far as I know, I can't use `$()`. How can I get the output without creating a subprocess?

Comment: Well, `var` is `pwd`, thus `echo ${var}` will output `pwd`...   Did you mean to run `$(echo ${var})`?

Comment: Think of `$()` as a variable and it will be easier to understand. Say a variable `$a` contains  pwd, then just typing `$a` will run the command where `var=$a` will assign the contents of `$a` (that is pwd, not the output of the command) to `var`. The same goes for `$()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(command line)
```

means to exeecute `command line`, and then substitute its output into the command line in place of that syntax. If you just have

```
$(echo "pwd")
```

as the whole command line, it executes `echo "pwd"`, gets the output `pwd`, and replaces that will the output, so it's equivalent to:

```
pwd
```

When you do:

```
var=$(echo "pwd")
```

The output of `echo "pwd"` is the string `pwd`, so it's the same as:

```
var="pwd"
```

Then when you do:

```
echo ${var}
```

it's the same as

```
echo "pwd"
```

If you want to execute the command, don't put `echo` before it, just do:

```
${var}
```

just like you didn't put `echo` before `$(echo "pwd")` in your original command.

If you want to get the output of this in another variable, you have to use `$()` again:

```
res=$(${var})
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification-it helps. When I run `${var}`, I get the output I need, however, when I try to assign the output: `res=${var}`, `echo ${res}`, I still get the *pwd* command. How do I retrieve the output?

Comment: If you want to substitute the output, you have to use `$()`: `res=$(${var})`

Comment: Barman, thank you. However, it doesn't work for me. See my edit.

Comment: You left out `res=`

Comment: Yes, on purpose, to check if the command itself works before trying to assign its output to a variable. Now I confirmed that it works if I retrieve the output. But why doesn't it work when I don't assign the output to the variable? What's the difference for the command?

Comment: If you just want to execute the command, type `${var}`. You only need to use `$()` if you want to substitute the output into another command, such as a variable assignment.

Comment: If you type `$(${var}))` it executes the command, then substitutes the output into the next command, so it tries to execute the output. But the output is the directory name, which isn't something you can execute.

Comment: Barmar, it doesn't work if I want to change the current working directory using `var`. I've read that it's because `$()` creates a subshell. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Changing directory doesn't produce any output, so why would you need to put `$()` around that?

Comment: But other commands do. I want to have a function `run_command` that will run any command and display the output if the command failed. I don't want to check the result of each bash command I execute.

Comment: Sorry, there's no general purpose way to do that for all commands. You can do it with external commands, because they always run in a new process anyway. But you can't do it with commands whose purpose is to change the current process's state, like `cd`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cmd="ls"
```

To run `$cmd` and print its output to the terminal, just evaluate the variable:

```
$ "$cmd"
file1 file2 dir1
```

To capture `$cmd`'s output, use `$(...)`.

```
$ a=$("$cmd")
$ echo "$a"
file1
file2
dir1
```

Why does these work? Every time you write `"$cmd"`, mentally substitute `ls`. Then you get

```
$ ls
file1 file2 dir1
```

and

```
$ a=$(ls)
$ echo "$a"
file1
file2
dir1
```

Why do the commands you tried fail? Because `a=$cmd` is equivalent to `a=ls`, which is the same as `a="ls"`. It simply assigns the string `ls` to the variable `a`. It doesn't execute the `ls` command.

To call `ls` you either need to write `ls` with no variable assignment, or use `$(...)` to capture its output.