# How do i pass first value of file to a variable?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a .txt File where there is data in it like

```
Ram
Raj
Viraj
```

I want to pass only first value *`Ram`* to a variable so that I can use its value further in the Linux command.

I have code which works but partially

```
head -1 demo.txt => gives me first value Ram
```

But How do I pass that value to a variable

Like this

```
$value head-1 demo.txt
$value = Ram
```

Not working ......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/608639), [How to assign the output of a Bash command to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2314750/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
value=$(head -1 demo.txt)
```

Comment: Why should one try that? Keep in mind that a good explanation helps others to understand your answer