# Shell How to get a new path by replacing a substring in a path string

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have a path like this:

```
dirname=../2Reconnaissance-annoted/J39/IMG_2208.json
```

I want to get a new path by replacing ".json" with "_json", so I tried this command:

```
tr "\.json" "_json" <<<$dirname
```

The problem is that I get:

```
__/2Reconnaissance-annoted/J39/IMG_2208_json
```

Rather than

```
../2Reconnaissance-annoted/J39/IMG_2208_json
```

How do you fix it, please?

Comment: try this: ```dirname=${dirname/.json/_json}```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/608639), [How to assign the output of a Bash command to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2314750/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr` does transliteration, i.e. it replaces a character by a character, not a string by a string. What you need is substitution.

Most shells support substitution directly:

```
dirname=${dirname/.json/_json}
```

(`${dirname/%.json/_json}` would only substitute the substrings at the end of the string).

If your shell doesn't support it, you can use `sed`:

```
echo "$dirname" | sed -e 's/\.json$/_json/'
```