# How to use variable in bash script

Tags: bash, cd

```
user= whoami
echo $user

cd /home/${user}
```

I unable to change directory by this method.

output

```
pbsh56@pbsh56:~/Documents$ source one.sh
pbsh56

pbsh56@pbsh56:/home$
```

Comment: no space after `=` !, and use `$()` if you want to capture the output of a command. Start at https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You may also use the `$HOME` system variable holding the path for your use, For  instance if your name is `"Joe"`, then `[ "$HOME" = /home/joe ]`.

Comment: [Notice no spaces after the equals sign.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2314765/1765658)

Comment: Before asking such a question, I recommend running your code with `set -x` turned on. You will see immediately where ther error is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Spacing is important.  Because of the space in your command, this doesn't do what you expect:

```
user= whoami
```

What that does is define an empty variable called `user`, and then calls the `whoami` command with that empty variable added to the environment.  The "pbsh56" you see is from the `whoami` command, not from the `echo`.

What you want is

```
user=$(whoami)
echo $user
cd /home/$user
```